# Flutter - ignore system Display Size setting

Tags: flutter

I'm having an issue regarding `devicePixelRatio` and Display Size settings on Android. App works great if Display Size is set to default, problems begin with bigger values. I know that for system Font Size setting I can just set `textScaleFactor` to 1.0 like so:

```
MaterialApp(
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child){
        return MediaQuery(
            data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                textScaleFactor: 1.0
            ),
            child: child,
        );
    },
)
```

I'm not sure if I can do the same for `devicePixelRatio` (which is affected by Display Size setting) or rather if there is a way I can obtain the default value of `devicePixelRatio`.

Answer (score -3):

> Try this!
>
> ```
> return MaterialApp(
>       navigatorKey: globals.navKey,
>       builder: (context, child) {
>         return MediaQuery(
>           child: child],
>           data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
>         );
>        }
>      );
> ```